# How to get results from txt files or merge few files in one?

Tags: python, r, bash, awk, merge

I have a problem with result files. I have a 103 ".txt" files. All of them contains data like this:

```
APSI:0.347
TC:0.130
CS:0.115
FI:0.375
```

I need to calculate the statistics but I need first have all values in one file. The best way to merge all files and import it to R or Python (in my opinion). Then I will create data frame and it will be easy to calculate.

But i have no idea how to merge files in one file 
to achieve this format:

```
APSI:0.XXX, 0.FFFF, 0.FFTR...
TC:0.XXX, 0.GSFF, 0.XXXX...
CS:0.RRR, 0.CGGG, 0.TTTT...
FI:0.TTT, 0.RRTT, 0.RRRR...
```

How to do that?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Have a look at `join`

Comment: Hi,
I did not expect anybody to write all the code doing this for me, but even some guidance, because I have no idea how to merge it. Regarding JOIN, is it about bash or are you talking about some other language? Which will be the best for this example?

Comment: If you have multiple input files then, obviously, show multiple input files in your example. Show at least 2 input files (3 would be better) plus the expected output given those input files, not some other output that is not derived from your input. Make sure you cover any edge cases (e.g. duplicate entries or missing entries, or key strings that are substrings of other strings, or null fields or....), not just the sunny day ones. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Also - you're question says you want statistics (but don't say what stats) but then your example shows you merging files which is almost certainly unnecessary. if you want statistics as output then show **that** in your question, don't just show what you think might be some intermediate step to getting to those statistics,.

Comment: I need to calculate statistics, and because it I need to have all values in one file. I know how to calculate this, just don't know how to merge files :) And in a post, I show example file. All files are the same but contain different values just I said :) 
Thanks very much for answers, very helpful! :)

Comment: `I need to calculate statistics` - understood but which ones or we can't show you how to do that. `and because it I need to have all values in one file` - no you don't you just need all files read into the tool at one time. If you want help with how to do that then ask a new, followup question as you've already accepted an answer to this one.

Comment: That question is already closed, I just edit some lines based on your advice for people who may find this post in the future. Balderman understood my problem in the first version, now I just do that more clear. Thanks again for the advice :)

Comment: Thats fine but I'm still not sure you get what I'm saying so let me be clear - there may be a better (in some specific way/ways) solution to your actual problem of generating stats from a bunch of files than the solution you have accepted and that better solution probably does not involve creating a merged file. If you would like to find out whether or not such a better solution exists then post a followup question.

Comment: Yeah, I understood. For this time it's (answer) enough for my actual problem (and yeah, it's doesn't create a merged file, just read lines from all files). If next time I need a similar solution, and it does not work, I will keep in mind what you wrote. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a folder with 2 (as an example) files that looks like:

```
APSI:0.347
TC:0.130
CS:0.115
FI:0.375
```

And

```
APSI:0.56
TC:0.11
CS:0.12
FI:0.345
KK:0.1234
```

The code below collect the data and store them in a dict where each key points to list of values. Based on this data structure you can do stats calculations.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

FILES_FOLDER = 'files'
data = defaultdict(list)
files = os.listdir(FILES_FOLDER)
for f in files:
    with open(os.path.join(FILES_FOLDER, f)) as input_file:
        lines = input_file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            tmp = line.split(':')
            key = tmp[0]
            value = tmp[1]
            data[key].append(float(value))

print('Here is the merged data:')
print(data)
```

Output:

```
Here is the merged data:
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'CS': [0.115, 0.12], 'FI': [0.375, 0.345], 'APSI': [0.347, 0.56], 'KK': [0.1234], 'TC': [0.13, 0.11]})
```

Comment: Thanks for u reply. It works, but if I try to merge 103 files i got 203 CS results, wherein files are 103. But I try to refactor it for my example. Thanks so much for the sample!

Comment: If you have 103 files each one of then contains CS only once you will get a list with 103 entries. Maybe you have few CS's in one file?

Comment: Yeah, it was my bad, I just tried to refactor code for my specific case, and did some mistakes. But now everything works. Thank u very much for the help!